# Regular Expression for number with prefix 65+?

Tags: regex

examples

```
65+98912839128319823
65+8192381923819238123
65+123123
65+908
```

Only numbers with prefix 65+.

Comment: `^65\+[\d]+$/gm`

Comment: @Sahil Gulati What if I want to limit the numeric length of 20 numbers

Comment: 20 numbers including prefix `65+`

Comment: @Sahil Gulati 20 numbers after prefix

Comment: you can use `^65\+\d{20}$` and for range use `^65\+\d{1,20}$`

Comment: Don't pile on additional requirements.  Ask what you want to ask up front, or post a new question.

Comment: `^65\+[\d]{1,20}$/gm`

Comment: The square brackets around the `[\d]` add nothing useful.  This presupposes that the OP is using a regex dialect which supports the `\d` shorthand for digits.  If not, use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `^65+[0-9]*`. This should work

Comment: This will match `65+` followed by nothing.